# Long operation in background Android

Tags: java, android

I'm using only Java.

I read on the internet that async task is now the past, now everyone uses something in the style of await in the Kotlin.
I checked this in Android Studio, it is true, IDE show me , AsyncTask giving memory leaks.

So what is the best way currently (2018) in Android (Java) to do operation in other thread ?

Comment: please give me feedback, why downvote this question

Comment: for background jobs you can use services. and AsyncTasks are not giving memory leaks if you manage them properly .

Comment: services is background but no in other thread

Comment: your question was long operation in background . well in that case you can make threads and communicate with handlers or broadcasts

Answer (score 0):

I useing threads backEnd and services. As i see bouth can do memory leak if not proper implemented but i stiil recomend service for long time run it's type of threads in my opionion(i fire backend services from other services and it's work in backend if u that meen by `services is background but no in other thread`

Answer (score 0):

You can use newest way to run background IO operation in background and UI operation in Main Thread , just see this example's [RxJava2](https://blog.gojekengineering.com/multi-threading-like-a-boss-in-android-with-rxjava-2-b8b7cf6eb5e2)